# apache mod_rewrite is not working completely

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please before u say its duplicated i know i have googled for hours but i dont know where the problem is i have a centos server with

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.27 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 26 2015 04:33:04
```

files are located in :

```
/home/user/public_html
```

ls -la:

```
index.php includes view.php .htaccess ...
```

when i try to open webpage site.com/view/test i do

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

but there is no error

this is my rules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^view/$ view.php
RewriteRule ^view$ view.php
RewriteRule ^view/(\w+)?$ view.php?cat=$1
```

it works fine on localhost (ubuntu 14.04 Desktop).

On server when i access

> site.com/view

its fine and shows me view.php but

> site.com/view/test

will not give me view.php?cat=test

Comment: Multiviews, Path info? Compare error and access.log, or enable the RewriteLog for diagnosis.

Comment: @mario i added some more info also there is a suphp 0.7.1

Comment: Not relevant. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained for "pitfalls". Show the rewrite.log, when you can't be more precise than "will not give me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex seems to be a problem as you have `(\w+)?` after `view/` in last rule causing `^view/$` rule to match **first always as it is placed before `^view/(\w+)?` rule**.

Try these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^view/?$ view.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^view/(\w+)/?$ view.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.